# In which operating systems must I use 'single dot followed by slash' when specifying a path name?

Tags: path, directory, operating-system, relative-path

I know that in Windows I don't have to do so.

For example, `./dir/file.ext` and `dir/file.ext` are equivalent.

Are these two forms possibly different on any other OS, e.g., Linux?

Or is it possibly application-dependent, in which case they might be treated differently even on Windows?

I am asking because I keep bumping into the usage of `./` at the beginning of path names (mostly but not only in NodeJS), and I would like to be sure that I can omit it safely (i.e., avoid turning my code platform-dependent).

Comment: That's only required in bash-like shells when executing a script / executable.

Comment: @SLaks: bash-like shells on any OS? So how would you be sure that there aren't any other types of applications which require it?

Answer (score 2):

The `./` you're referring to is specific to UNIX-like operating systems (OSX and Linux are the major examples) and not program specific. On those platforms, it is used to execute the file being referred to, while in Windows merely typing an executable's filename will execute it. I don't know if the code you're referring to determines which OS you're on, but if it's true that Windows ignores the period, then this is a useful cross-platform method to execute an executable.